# Error in C#: The type or namespace name > `FTDI_Mgt' could not be found / missing an assembly reference

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi, mono, program-entry-point

I can't figure what is the wrong with my code below. Compiling on Linux/raspberry using Mono,mcs.

When I try to compile using (mcs) I get the message:

> FTDI_Mgt.cs(15,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> `FTDI_Mgt' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

This is part of my code in a file named **FTDI_Mgt.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using FTD2XX_NET;
using myGenericTool;

namespace ST_NBIOT_TOOL
{
    public partial class FTDI_Mgt1: FTDI_Mgt             ///// line 15
    {

//..
        public FTDI_Mgt()       ////// line 51
        {
            Init_timerGetData();

        }
        private void Init_timerGetData()
        {
            timerGetData = new Timer();
            timerGetData.Interval = 5;
            timerGetData.Tick += new EventHandler(ReadData_Tick);
       }
```

My **Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_NBIOT_TOOL
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FTDI_Mgt1());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried by changing Application.Run(new FTDI_Mgt1()) to Application.Run(new **FTDI_Mgt**()) AND ligne 15 in FTDI_Mgt.cs to **public class FTDI_Mgt**
I got this error:

> FTDI_Mgt.cs(51,16): error CS1520: Class, struct, or interface method
> must have a return type

Any idea please? Any help? Did I miss something? I am not an expert in C#!

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you are not an expert of C#, you should try to use a MSBuild project to build source files, not mcs command line (where you can miss quite a lot). Besides, use .NET Core instead of Mono.

Comment: Where is line 51 column 16?

Comment: @jdweng line 51 is the constructor method ( public FTDI_Mgt() ) in FTDI_Mgt.cs

Comment: @LexLi thank you for your comment, but I have no choice, working without desktop

Comment: If you are compiling on linux you need to use the SDK (left column) and not the runtime library (right column) https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1: